# cross-parsing in function input parameters

Tags: r, parsing

This really falls under the purview of "Don't **DO** that!" ,but..

I wrote this to see what would happen.

```
circit <-function(x=deparse(substitute(y)),y=deparse(substitute(x)))
{
return(list(x=x,y=y))
}
```

Two examples:

```
> circit()
$x
[1] "deparse(substitute(x))"

$y
[1] "deparse(substitute(y))"

> circit(3)
$x
[1] 3

$y
[1] "3"
```

Notice the subtle swap of "x" and "y" in the output.
I can't follow the logic, so can someone explain how the argument parser handles this absurd pair of default inputs?   (the second case is easy to follow)

Comment: "x" evaluates to <deparse the non evaluated "y"> where <non evaluated "y"> is the `deparse(substitute(x))` "call" construct which is deparsed while "x" is evaluated. Instead of `deparse(substitute(x))`, a simpler call like `circit(, 3 + pi ^ 1.24)$x` shows that "x" just evaluates to deparsing the unevaluated "y" call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key thing to understand/remember is that formal arguments are promise objects, and that `substitute()` has special rules for how it evaluates promise objects. As explained in `?substitute`, it returns their expression slot, not their value:

> Substitution takes place by examining each component of the parse
>        tree as follows: If it is not a bound symbol in ‘env’, it is
>        unchanged.  If it is a promise object, i.e., a formal argument to
>        a function or explicitly created using ‘delayedAssign()’, the
>        expression slot of the promise replaces the symbol.  If it is an
>        ordinary variable, its value is substituted, unless ‘env’ is
>        ‘.GlobalEnv’ in which case the symbol is left unchanged.

To make this clearer, it might help to walk through the process in detail. In the first case, you call  `circuit()` with no supplied arguments, so `circuit()` uses the default values of both `x=` and `y=`.

For `x`, that means its value is gotten by evaluating `deparse(substitute(y))`. The symbol `y` in that expression is matched by the formal argument `y`, a promise object. `substitute()` replaces the symbol `y` with its expression slot, which holds the expression `deparse(substitute(x))`. Deparsing that expression returns the text string `"deparse(substitute(x))"`, which is what gets assigned to `x`'s value slot.

Likewise, the value of `y` is gotten by evaluating the expression `deparse(substitute(x))`. The symbol `x` is matched by the formal argument `x`, a promise object. Even though the **value** of `x` is something else, its expression slot is still `deparse(substitute(y))`, so that's what's returned by evaluating `substitute(x)`. As a result, `deparse(substitute(x))` returns the string `"deparse(substitute(y))"`

Comment: This answer is very difficult to follow. I'd have found an explicit demonstration  of `deparse(substitute(deparse(substitute(y))))` much clearer.

Comment: It's also curious that R doesn't simply explode and only follows the promises once.

Comment: Thanks.  I figured it was based on the delay in promises, but didn't follow the sequence all the way.

Comment: @eddi here you go:  `circit2 <-function(x=deparse(substitute(deparse(substitute(y)))),y=deparse(substitute(x)))
+ {
+ return(list(x=x,y=y))
+ }
> circit2()
$x
[1] "deparse(substitute(deparse(substitute(x))))"

$y
[1] "deparse(substitute(deparse(substitute(y))))"`

Comment: @CarlWitthoft that's not what I mean - it's not obvious that this chain should stop on 2nd expression: `x = deparse(substitute(y)) = deparse(substitute(deparse(substitute(x)))) = deparse(substitute(deparse(substitute(deparse(substitute(y)))))) = ...`

Comment: @eddi -- I agree it's hard to follow, and would welcome other suggestions for improvement! Like you, I started by thinking of just showing the result of `deparse(substitute(deparse(substitute(x))))` and its result. Unfortunately, that doesn't quite address the subtlety of what's going on, since in that example, `deparse(substitute(x))` isn't a promise object, and the fact that the arguments `x` and `y` are promise objects is precisely what prevents the endless recursion you're wondering about.

Comment: @eddi Because `substitute()` just asks for and returns the expression slot of `x` and of `y`, its evaluation doesn't go even one step down that rabbit hole you're describing.